# How to pass multirange in VBA functions as parameter?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

```
Public Function iQuery(pName As Varient, pTime As Varient)
For Each item in pName
   ...
Next item
End Function
```

I have a function named iQuery and I want to pass range `$A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6` as pName and range `$A$19` as pTime but it picks `$A$3` as pName and `$A$4` as pTime when iQuery is called as `iQuery($A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6,$A$19)`

Comment: in VBA as Range.FormulaArray = "=iQuery($A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6,$A$19)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this from VBA then you need to pass the range as range objects. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim Ret As ??????

    Set rngA = Range("$A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6")
    Set rngB = Range("$A$4")

    Ret = iQuery(rngA, rngB)
End Sub

Public Function iQuery(pName As Range, pTime As Range) As ??????
    Dim itm As Range

    For Each itm In pName
       ...
    Next itm
End Sub
```

Where `??????` is the relevant datatype you want to return.

If you are doing this from the worksheet then pass it as one range. For example

```
=iQuery($A$3:$A$6,$A$19)
```

> But What if sFormula is "=iQuery($A$3,$B$14,$C$11,$A$6,$A$19)" and I want first parameter to be $A$3,$B$14,$C$11,$A$6 and second one $A$19 – rs4 18 mins ago

For non contigous ranges, use a bracket. For example

```
=iQuery(($A$3,$B$14,$C$11,$A$6),$A$19)
```

Comment: How to use in case of Range.FormulaArray

Comment: Can you exaplain what you exactyl want?

Comment: I have a range named `rOut` and I'm assigning `rOut.FormulaArray = sFormula` Where `sFormula` is `"=iQuery($A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6,$A$19)"`

Comment: Then change `"=iQuery($A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6,$A$19)"` to `"=iQuery($A$3:$A$6,$A$19)"`

Comment: But What if `sFormula` is `"=iQuery($A$3,$B$14,$C$11,$A$6,$A$19)"` and I want first parameter to be `$A$3,$B$14,$C$11,$A$6` and second one `$A$19`